# Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl how the Driver will accept the url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

the given below is my pom.xml file and also the application.properties file please reveiw the code and help me out

my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.exam</groupId>
    <artifactId>examserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>examserver</name>
    <description>Backend code for exam portal</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>


     <!--added-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In these code below I have changed the port and added the `DEBUG` line also rest of the code is same from before

my `application.properties` file

```
#added
#logging.level.com.exam=DEBUG
server.port=8180
##

#database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql//localhost:3307/exam?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=7057@Avi

spring.datasource.driver-class=com.cj.jdbc.Driver

#jpa configuration
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Please give me the solution, so that my project can be able to create the database and I can move further in it

Comment: `h2` is not `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal since you are trying to put a mysql configuration while using h2

```
A link for h2 [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mistake charactor **mysql:**

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:**mysql**//localhost:3307/exam?serverTimezone=UTC

Change to :

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:**mysql:**//localhost:3307/exam?serverTimezone=UTC

"also make sure your mysql is running with port 3307"

Comment: done brother thank you so much for helping me out , there was an error in the sql server port